# WinRT -TimePicker control

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am looking fora timepicker control for WinRT. I have looked at few nuget packages like callisto and winrtxaml but they dont seem to have it. Is there any package online which implements it ?

Something Like this-[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is one coming with Windows 8.1. Otherwise (if you need it for 8.0) there are some component libraries that come with one - see a list [here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/). If I were to choose to do more work over paying a few dollars to get one - I'd check if the Windows Phone Toolkit had one and port it to Windows 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Visual Studio, I would highly recommend Synfusion's XAML Studio. You can check my Blog Post on DatePicker Control here, http://darkcore.in/getting-started-with-syncfusions-date-picker-control-for-winrt/

You can also visit their Official Site : www.syncfusion.com

Regards